# Attempting to retrieve XML data through API and saving the output in tabular format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using the below code to collect XML data via an API request. I'm currently getting output in a list format, as seen below, but I'd like to get it in a tabular style. Is there any recommended code adjustment here

````
import xmltodict
import json
import csv
 
url = "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml"
 
response = requests.get(url)
content=xmltodict.parse(response.text)
json_data = json.loads(json.dumps(content))
plant_data = json_data['CATALOG']['PLANT']
data_file = open('data_file.csv', 'w')  
csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file)   
count = 0  
for plant in plant_data: 
    if count == 0:    
        header = plant.keys() 
        csv_writer.writerow(header) 
        count += 1  
    # Writing data of CSV file 
    csv_writer.writerow(plant.values())     
data_file.close() ```

XML Input Format :

**<CATALOG>
<PLANT>
<COMMON>Bloodroot</COMMON>
<BOTANICAL>Sanguinaria canadensis</BOTANICAL>
<ZONE>4</ZONE>
<LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
<PRICE>$2.44</PRICE>
<AVAILABILITY>031599</AVAILABILITY>
</PLANT>**

> Current Output is in below List format :

**['Bloodroot', 'Sanguinaria canadensis', '4', 'Mostly Shady', '$2.44', '031599']**

> I'm trying to get output something like this in a tabular format below:

|COMMON     |BOTANICAL     | ZONE  |LIGHT | PRICE |AVAILABILITY |
|:--------- |:-----------: |:-----:|:-----:|:----:|------------:|
| Bloodroot |Sangunia cande| 4     |M Shady| $2.44| 031599      |


Any ideas for improving the above code to read the header and value in tabular format
````

Answer (score 0):

The csv module already supports alternate delimiters so just specify tab.

```
csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file, delimiter='\t')
```